# Safari not showing all Facebook icons

Tags: macos, safari, icon, facebook

sometimes when i login facebook the profile picture icons just won't load. I tried reseting safari, nothing. When i use chrome everything is ok. I googled it and someone said something about deleting a cache file but i could not find in library the safari cache file (i have no idea what it means, i guess some of you will understand).
I have the safari Version 7.0.2 (9537.74.9) and OS X 10.9.2. Anyone got an idea of how to fix it? Thank you in advance

[image: a random printscreen, some icons load some don't]

Answer (score 1):

To empty the Safari caches, first you need to have the Develop menu displayed in the menu bar (Preferences | Advanced | Show Develop menu in menu bar). Then on the Develop menu, click on Empty Caches.

You can also use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

Comment: LOL! Thanks @aris. Feel free to mark this answer as the correct solution. :)